# Include URL with underscore in it - ASCIIDOC

Tags: escaping, asciidoc

I am trying to include a reference to a link, containing an underscore inside. I've tried to escape it with a backslash, or to encode it - nothing works so far. Any ideas how is this done in ASCIIDOC?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like enclosing it in double dollar signs might work (see http://themes.asciidoctor.org/preview/)

For example, if I want to output "_design/dev_patient", then I would use asciidoc `$$_$$design/dev_patient`

Comment: This worked for me. See also this asciidoctor issue with more suggestions: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/625